# Code does not output entire string but instead only a part of it

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that ouputs the ENTIRE string from scanf if the string contains a certain word. Why is it that if the input from scanf has spaces in it, the program only outputs the special word and not the entire string if the input contains the word?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char inputString[40];
    char *word = "azir";
    int exit = 1;
    while(exit != 0){
        scanf("%s", &inputString);
        exit = stricmp("exit", inputString);
        if(strstr(inputString, word) != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", inputString);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @haccks I had to look it up as well. Quite similar to POSIX `strcasecmp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `scanf()`, use `fgets()` to get the entire line.  `scanf()` will ignore whitespace while looking for a string token (and even then will only read to the next bit of whitespace on the line), `fgets()` will get everything up to and including the EOL character on the line.

Comment: Great, I'm pretty new to C. Thank you

Comment: @haccks - fgets, from its manpage: "fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.** A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer."

Comment: @JohnH; C11: 7.21.7.2: *The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n
from the `stream` pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional
characters are read after a new-line character (**which is retained**) or after end-of-file. A
null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.*

Comment: @haccks  Confused about your comment "fgets doesn't read \n".  Certainly `fgets()` does read and save a `'\n'` albeit only up to 1 `'\n'`.

Comment: `scanf("%s")` will ignore leading whitespace.  Many other format directives for `scanf()` do not ignore whitespace.

Comment: @chux; I already quoted from standard in my previous comment.